# Power Bi DAX: Reset Value past a date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Run into a problem.

I need to have a yearly reset on an entitlement value but the reset point is a different date for each person. A person gets entitlement 6 months after their start date, so that +6months date is when they should have a reset. Here is the +6months column i made:

```
+6m = DATE(YEAR('Employee List'[Emp. Dates]),
           MONTH('Employee List'[Emp. Dates])+6,
           DAY('Employee List'[Emp. Dates]))
```

I ran into this problem when i saw that the excess was taking away a persons entitlement by the amount of days took throughout their entire time at the company. Here is the measure for Excess:

```
Excess Days = CALCULATE(SUM('Employee List'[Entitlement]) - 
                        SUM('Leave combined'[Duration1]))
```

This is taking away all recorded days even from a few years ago.

Can i make a measure that pretty much says if we are past the +6months date (DD/MM(Year doesnt matter i just need the same time every year)), then it will take away their entitlement from that +6months date and will not pick up any days from before the +6months reset?

e.g. if the +6months is March 1 2015, currently it is taking all the days took from their start to today, i want it to reset at every year on March 1 so it would only take data from March 1 2019 - today and will reset once we past March 1 2020. If a person has took 25 days a year on average and they only have 20 days entitlement, it should show they 5 excess days but for me now it is taking the total days took away from their entitlement.

I understand this is hard to explain and you may not get it but i am happy enough to explain.

[Dummy Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY2Py.png)

Comment: Sample data and desired output would be really helpful here

Comment: Please refer to the last paragraph

Comment: I did, but in order to actually write a calculation, we would need to understand all the elements involved. It makes it much easier to help, when you have a sample data to work with. It does not have to be anything major, just a few records of what your data is looking like right now should do. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I have an excel sheet i could show but how do i send it?

Comment: Just attach a screenshot of the first few records to the question

Comment: I added a dummy sheet at the bottom of my question. As you can see the left is all data i am using, the stop right table is an example of the entitlement, start date and +6months. Below that in the box is the output. The duration is 16 because i only taken data from 30/05/2019 as the +6months date is 05/04 so we cannot use any data before that date. The excess is entitlement - duration

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to create a calculated column to do this. Perhaps something like:

```
Calc =
     VAR Person = TableA[Person]
     VAR Date1 = EDATE(Entitlement[Start Date],6)
RETURN IF(TableA[Start]<Date1,0,TableA[Duration])
```

This column will make the duration 0, wherever the start date is lesser than the +6m date from entitlement. Once this column is created you can simply sum up the field at whatever level required, to get the desired output. Hope this helps.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the duration, +6Months / Start Date and Entitlement are all from different tables. I can use the start date for the EDATE and RETURN IF. Im new to DAX so sorry for the annoyance.

Comment: The above calculation assumes that you have two different tables - TableA and Entitlement. Is the calculation not working?